# fast function for generating bootstrap samples in matrix forms in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I have a matrix `A`, and I would like to draw samples from each column of `A` and construct new matrices. For example:

`A = matrix(seq(1,9),3,3)`

so to get the 1st bootstrap matrix, I would sample with replacement (3 times) from the first column of `A`, i.e. 1,2,3, sample with replacement (3 times) from the second column of `A`, i.e. 4,5,6, and sample with replacement (3 times) from the third column of `A`, i.e. 7,8,9. After that, I re-construct the 1st bootstrap matrix B1 by combining the three bootstrap vectors. I will repeat this procedure for B=199 times, so that bootstrap matrices B1,...,B199 will be available.

My question is, how can I make this program run faster? Which function should I use? I know `apply` involves essentially `for` loops so the speed is not guaranteed. How about `do.call`? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `replicate` and `apply`:

```
A <- matrix(seq(1,9),3,3)

B <- 199

replicate(B, apply(A, 2, sample, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: thanks, but the use of `sample` is to sample without replacement. Here I hope to get bootstrap sample, so how can I pass `replace=TRUE` to the function?

Comment: I got it: `replicate(B, apply(A, 2, function(s) sample(s,replace=TRUE)))` will work :)